# Insert Property List plist in UML

Tags: iphone, uml, property-list

I programmed an IPhone app, and I have to design the UML now. (I know wrong order)

Question: Are the Property Lists, where I save my data designed in UML or not? And if so, how are they connected, association, aggregation,...?

example:

```
NSString *path=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ArticleData.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *data=[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]autorelease];
...
[data setObject:articleId forKey@"id"];
...
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have iphone compatible UML tool.

Comment: I'm pretty sure their is none. Apparently you can create UML's in xcode, but you can't convert your project into uml, so I still don't know if I can use plists in uml. The only thing I found out is that plist are an XML format, and xml can be displayed in uml, so it should work.